# Double taskbar icon android studio

Tags: windows-7, android-studio

I just installed Android Studio and got it working but unfortunately, as it happened for Eclipse, when I pin it to the taskbar every time it is started it doubles itself (with a slightly different icon actually). 
How can I have solve this issue?

Comment: see:[Duplicate icons on taskbar in IntelliJ – Windows 10](http://superuser.com/questions/954300/duplicate-icons-on-taskbar-in-intellij-windows-10)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of launching Android Studio via the studio.exe located in the root folder, launch it via *studio.exe* (*studio64.exe* in case of 64-bit JDK) located in the *bin* folder. This should fix the nasty double icon issue that you are experiencing. Note however that the *studio.exe* file I have mentioned is available in the *bin* folder starting from Android Studio version 0.1.3.

Comment: Sorry but I have /bin/studio.exe.vmoptions or /bin/studio64.exe.vmoptions. The only studio.exe I have is in the root folder

Comment: You will have the files once you update to the latest version. Which version of Android Studio are you using?

Comment: The version is the first one, 0.1.1

Comment: As I mentioned, the files would be there starting from version 0.1.3. You have to update in case you want this issue (and many other issues as well - http://tools.android.com/recent/androidstudio013released) fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I reported and fixed it for AS 0.8.12 version (the currenty version).

Please see the step by step to fix it for any AS version:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=77439

HTH.